# my dynamically populated radio button group gets more than one item checked. so how to solve this.?using HTML,CSS,JS; C#(backend)

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, css

my dynamically populated radio button group gets more than one item checked. so how to solve this.?using HTML,CSS,JS; C#(backend).
i wrote a code for list of items with input type as "radio". the values of list item is stored in a Arraylist in backend i.e C#. but when i try to run the code, more than one radio button gets selected.
please help me solve my issue. and even how to check which radio value is selected and how to pass the checked radio value to backend or server.
HTML code

```
<div class="demo-container size-thin">
                <div class="RadListBox RadListBox_Silk"  >
                    <div class="rlbGroup">
                        <ul>
                        <%
                            foreach (var item in dataname)
                            {
                        %>
                            <li>
                            <input type="radio" />
                            <img alt="" src="Images/<%=item %>.png">   <%= item%></li>
                        <%
                            }
                        %> 

                        </ul>

                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
```

[Sample frontend visual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1NIc.jpg)
i have not writeen any javascript code as of now.

Comment: You have to put a name to your radios.

Comment: give same name to all radio buttons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be clearer than the other answers. **All radio buttons in a group must have identical values for their `name` attribute.** This is what groups them together. It's their `value` attribute that is used to give each button its individual meaning.

Additionally, the `name` attribute is necessary for any/all form elements that are supposed to submit their value during the `submit` event. If an element doesn't have the `name` attribute, it won't send its data.

Once you've made this change, you don't have to worry about how to send the checked radio button's value to the backend server because that will be done automatically when the `form` that the radio button is in gets submitted.

```js
// Get reference to parent element of first radio button group 
var parent = document.querySelector("fieldset:first-child");

// Set up click event handler for it
parent.addEventListener("click", function(e){
  // Check to see if the originator of the event was a radio button
  if(e.target.nodeName === "INPUT" && e.target.getAttribute("type") === "radio"){
    // Get a reference to the checked radio button
    console.log("Checked radio button is: " + 
      document.querySelector("input[type=radio][name=testGroup1]:checked").value); 
  }
});
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Group 1</legend>

  <label> Choice A<input type="radio" name="testGroup1" value="A"></label><br>
  <label> Choice B<input type="radio" name="testGroup1" value="B"></label><br>
  <label> Choice C<input type="radio" name="testGroup1" value="C"></label>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
  <legend>Group 2</legend>

  <label> Choice A<input type="radio" name="testGroup2" value="A"></label><br>
  <label> Choice B<input type="radio" name="testGroup2" value="B"></label><br>
  <label> Choice C<input type="radio" name="testGroup2" value="C"></label>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: thanks for the solution. But how can i access the checked value of the radio list as soon as the user checks it i.e without waiting for the form to be submitted.

Comment: @sourav Answer updated to show this. But, just know that you usually don't  even have to worry about getting the checked radio button at all unless you need to do some sort of additional client-side processing on it. Since radio buttons are mutually exclusive, only the checked one will send its data to the server during a form submit.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give a name to it

`<input type="radio" name="myRadio">`

this way the radio know which "group" is it from

[input radio](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio)

Answer (score 0):

@Sourav,
First, we've to set the name of that radio button.

```
<input type="radio" name="nameOfThisField">
```